# What is the supposed behavior of copy-list-initialization in the case of an initializer with a conversion operator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, g++, clang++

```
class AAA {
public:
    AAA() {}
    AAA(const AAA&) {}
};

class BBB {
public:
    BBB() {}
    operator AAA() { AAA a; return a; }
};

int main() {
    BBB b;
    AAA a = {b};
}
```

The above code compiles on g++ and vc++, but not clang++.
The traditional syntax `AAA a = b;` compiles ok on all three.

```
class AAA {};

class BBB {
public:
    BBB() {}
    operator AAA() { AAA a; return a; }
};

int main() {
    BBB b;
    AAA a = {b};
}
```

The above code doesn't compile on any of g++, vc++, clang++.  The only difference against the first code snippet is that I removed the two user-provided constructors of AAA.
Again, the traditional syntax `AAA a = b;` compiles ok on all three.

I'm quite sure that the traditional syntax of copy-initialization is well-defined in the case of an initializer with a conversion operator.  But for the C++11 copy-list-initialization, I'm confused.  Is clang taking the correct action rejecting the initialization or g++/vc++ taking the correct action accepting the initialization (as seen in the first code snippet)?  And why such a trivial change as done in the second code snippet will result in that significant different behavior?  What's the difference between copy-list-initialization and traditional copy-initialization in this case after all?

EDIT: Adding a third case:

```
class CCC {};

class AAA {
public:
    AAA() {}
    AAA(const AAA&) {}
    AAA(const CCC&) {}
};


class BBB {
public:
    BBB() {}
    operator CCC() {CCC c; return c;}
};

int main() {
    BBB b;
    AAA a = {b};
}
```

The above code compiles for all three compilers.  The conversion operator works if the final destination constructor is not the copy constructor?
In this case, the traditional syntax `AAA a = b;` fails to compile for all three as expected, since traditional copy-initialization allows one level of user-defined implicit conversion at most before arriving at the final copy constructor (the final destination can only be the copy constructor).

Begging for a systematic explanation for all these mess...

Comment: I think clang is correct in both cases.

Comment: So it's g++/vc++'s bug in the fist code snippet?  And though both copy-list-initialization and traditional copy-initialization can handle conversion through the destination type's constructor, only the traditional copy-initialization can handle conversion through the source type's conversion operator.  Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: I've changed my mind. I think clang is wrong in the first case from looking at 8.5.4 [decl.init.list]. The standard mentions narrowing conversions for list-initialisation but this doesn't seem to exclude conversion operators or constructors.

Comment: I think it's a bug with clang, since the standard explicitly mentions in the case of an initializer list with a single element, *the object or reference is initialized from that element* (dcl.init.list p3).

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: Do you have any idea of what's happening in the second code snippet?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis But then  13.3.3.1/4 says: *by 13.3.1.7 when passing the initializer list as a single argument or **when the initializer
list has exactly one element and a conversion to some class X or reference to (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) X is
considered for the ﬁrst parameter of a constructor of X**, or by 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5, or 13.3.1.6 in all cases, **only
standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first, you are hitting http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1673 (see the last testcase): If list initialization passes only a single element to a copy/move constructor of some class `X`, user defined conversions are not allowed on that single element to convert it to the `X` parameter. Also see http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12117 which made Clang implement this rule

For the second: You are hitting http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1467 (but instead of using an object of the same type, you use an object of an unrelated type). Your aggregate simply doesn't provide a data member of type `BBB`.

For the third: Neither of the above two situations apply, so the list initialization works and calls the `CCC` constructor of `AAA`. The `= b` initialization fails because it is only allowed to try converting the `b` to an `AAA` in a single user defined conversion sequence. But here you would need to first convert to `CCC` and then to `AAA` again. For list initialization, this restriction of doing only one user defined conversion does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  Just to confirm, for the second, it fails to compile because `AAA` is an aggregate and `AAA a = {b};` falls into the form of aggregate initialization which result in something like too many initializers.  Is that correct?

Comment: indeed that's the case

Comment: And for the first, the issue title of the link you pointed to is "Clarifying overload resolution for the second step of copy-initialization".  But in my case, isn't `BBB::operator AAA()` involved in the first step?

Comment: @goodbyeera yes, the issue is about that entire paragraph in which the "second step of copy initialization" is only one particular thing in it, but your issue is only about one particular other thing in that paragraph.