# Need help understanding "{}-initializer syntax minimizes the chances for unfortunate conversions"

Tags: c++, c++11

In "The C++ Programming Language" 4th edition page 164:

> When we explicitly mention the type of an object we are initializing,
>   we have two types to consider: the type of the object and the type of
>   the initializer. For example:
>
> ```
> char v1 = 12345; // 12345 is an int
> int v2 = 'c'; // 'c' is a char
> T v3 = f();
> ```
>
> By using the {}-initializer syntax for such definitions, we minimize
>   the chances for unfortunate conversions:
>
> ```
> char v1 {12345}; // error : narrowing
> int v2 {'c'}; // fine: implicit char->int conversion
> T v3 {f()}; // works if and only if the type of f() can be implicitly converted to a T
> ```

I don't quite understand the sentence `minimize the chances for unfortunate conversions` and the comment for `T v3 {f()};` that it `works if and only if the type of f() can be implicitly converted to a T`.  Consider the following two cases:

- a) If T has an explicit constructor taking an argument of the type of f().
- b) If the type of f() has a conversion operator to some type X and T has a constructor taking an argument of type X.

For both cases, the type of f() can't be implicitly converted to T, but `T v3 {f()}` is well-formed, so at least the `only if` part of that comment seems not appropriate?  (Also not sure whether the `if` part is right or not.)
And for both cases, it is `T v3 = f();` that is ill-formed, so what does the sentence `minimize the chances for unfortunate conversions` mean here?  It seems that {}-initializer is actually accepting more conversion forms (whether it's unfortunate or not is another question).  (Preventing narrowing is illustrated in the case of `v1` and that's clear.  I'm confused about `v3`.)

Answer (score 0):

It actually does conversions in other way than it was default.

Using one of your examples, `char x = 12345;` will actually cut down this value to last 8 bits since that's the size of char. With `{}` notation, it rises error since it's not approperiate.

Not this was sometimes (ab)used to get special effects, so it was left as default option in new C++, while new notation is used to provide better behaviour with less room for errors.

Comment: As I've said in the question, "`Preventing narrowing is illustrated in the case of v1 and that's clear. I'm confused about v3`".  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion:

```
char v1 = 12345;
```

is *unfortunate* because it is almost certainly not what the programmer wants:

- either we want a type which can represent the value 12345,
- or we used the correct type, but a wrong value

For `v3` the same applies, but in a more complicated context. The first snippet will force the compiler to consider *user-defined conversion sequences*. This increases potential for error; after all, we may be mis-implementing a conversion operator, made a typo, or otherwise managed to fit a round peg in a square hole. Using copy-list-initialization, we exclude user-defined conversion sequences, making conversion a lot safer.

For an example and detailed explanation of why this is happening, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829678/what-is-the-supposed-behavior-of-copy-list-initialization-in-the-case-of-an-init).

Comment: The question you add the link to is actually asked by me, if you haven't noticed yet :-)  I'm aware of that case.  As for the question here, I'm more confused by the cases that are rejected by `T v3 = f();` but accepted by `T v3 {f()};`, as I mentioned the in the question.  With these cases, is it still reasonable to say that the {}-initializer minimizes the chances for unfortunate conversions?  (And per my personal taste, the scenario rejected in the linked question is less unfortunate than the scenario accepted in the question here.)

Answer (score 0):

The comment for the initialization of `v3`:

```
T v3 {f()}; // works if and only if the type of f() can be implicitly converted to a T
```

is not strictly correct. That initialization works if and only if the type of `f()` can be *explicitly* converted to `T`. This syntax:

```
T v3 = {f()}; // truly does work if and only if the type of f()
              // can be implicitly converted to a T
```

(copy-list-initialization instead of direct-list-initialization) truly does require the conversion to be implicit. The difference is illustrated by this program:

```
struct T {
  explicit T(int) {}
};

int f() { return 0; }

int main() {
  T v3 = {f()};
}
```

in which the initialization will be diagnosed as ill-formed, since it selects an explicit constructor for `T` ([Live demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dde9ba9250b0f8bb)).