# Brace initialization subtleties

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

While trying to use **brace initialization**, a subtlety that can be found is when using `std::vector`, like showed in the following sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void print(const char * msg, const vector<T>& v) {
    cout << msg << endl;
    cout << "Size: " << v.size() << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "#" << (i+1) << ": " << v[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> vs{3};
    print("vector<string> vs{3};", vs);

    vector<int> vi{3};
    print("vector<int> vi{3};", vi);
}
```

The output is:

> ```
> vector<string> vs{3};
> Size: 3
> #1:
> #2:
> #3:
> ---------------------
> vector<int> vi{3};
> Size: 1
> #1: 3
> ---------------------
> ```

So, in the first case, the (so called...) *uniform* initialization initializes a vector conatining three empty strings, instead in the second case it initializes a vector containing just one integer having the value 3.

Besides this, are there other "gotchas" and subtleties to consider when using the new brace initialization style?

Comment: Well, indeed, if a constructor accepts a single argument of type `initializer_list`, then that constructor is eligible...

Comment: Not-so-subtle would be silent bad code-gen bugs with MSVC in VS2013: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044488/known-compiler-bug-in-vc12

Comment: In C++11, you can't copy-initialize an aggregate via braced-init-lists, see [CWG issue 1467](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1467).

Comment: There's also a subtlety in the allowed conversions, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21829678/420683

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you already understand the greedy nature of initializer-list constructors for containers. For the other surprising "gotchas" see [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847960/which-greedy-initializer-list-examples-are-lurking-in-the-standard-library) where I got tripped by this

```
std::string{ 65, 'C' } // NOT 65 times 'C', but "AC" ('A' is 65th character).
```