# Compilers behave differently with regards to std::move and deleted copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++17

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct A {};

struct B {
  B(A&&) {}
  B(const B&) = delete;
};

static void func(B) {}

int main() {
  A a;
  func(std::move(a));
}
```

This program is accepted by:

- GCC since 7.1 with `-std=c++17`
- GCC trunk (perhaps with C++17 as default?)
- clang since 5.0 with `-std=c++17`
- MSVC all versions I could find.

Was the standard changed regarding this in C++17? Is MSVC wrong in accepting this before C++17?

Comment: What is the difference in behaviors of compilers?

Comment: `std::cout << __cplusplus << "\n";` to see if C++17 is the default.

Answer (score 4):

MSVC is wrong. For [guaranted copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) since C++17,

> The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would
> otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be
> present or accessible:
>
> - In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the
>   variable type:

Given `func(std::move(a));`, `std::move(a)` is used to construct a temporary `B` via `B::B(A&&)` firstly, then the temporary is copied as the parameter to `func` via `B::B(const B&)`. The copy operation is omitted at all, the parameter is constructed from `std::move(a)` directly via `B::B(A&&)`.

Before C++17, this is an optimization, the copy/move constructor still must be present and accessible.

Comment: I would have expected construction in place here, I don't see copy/move here from `B`. (accepted syntax is `func({std::move(a)})` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dWdroMfPK)).

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't get the difference, why `func({std::move(a)});` doesn't need the copy/move? Doesn't it still construct a temporary `B` then copy-pass to `func`?

Comment: I don't see the difference neither. (but for me, they both construct in place, so without copy ;-) ).

Comment: @Jarod42 As OP said, `func(std::move(a));` can't compile with [pre-C++17 mode](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JZ6PP6GfPl0v9hNp), while `func({std::move(a)});` [can](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NwD61Jpl3NPIymZG). Hmm...

Comment: I was surprised that the code doesn't compile in C++14. (I expected `func(std::move(a));` and `func({std::move(a)});` do the same (success to compile), but only the later is valid :-/ ).

Comment: Don't know whether it helps but without braces, the function parameter is _copy-intialized_ while with braces, it is _copy-list-initialized_. It's the same as `B b = std::move(a);` and `B b = {std::move(a)};`, where only the latter compiles in C++11/14.

Comment: @DanielLangr I expected copy-initialization and copy-list-initliazation, i.e. `B b = std::move(a);` and `B b = {std::move(a)};` have the same behavior..

Comment: @songyuanyao I would expect the same, but the rules seem to differ: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization vs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes. It seems even befor C++17 copy-list-initliazation would bypass the copy/move operation, i.e. initialize the object directly.

Comment: I just checked with the C++11 standard and the rules really differ. With _copy-initialization_, the conversion results in a temporary. This is then used to call copy/move constructor, which is typically elided. On the contrary, _copy-list-initialization_ does not create any temporary and just the conversion constructor is involved. Relevant question: [Any difference between copy-list-initialization and traditional copy-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21825933/580083)